# How to fetch data from model and all of his childrens?

Tags: django, django-queryset

i have models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category, etc.)
    ...
```

I would like to retrieve all articles in category, also including child categories to the bitter end.

Ex:

```
Cat_1
\-Cat_2
  \-Cat_3
    \-Cat_4 (article_1)
  \-Cat3a (article_2)
```

How to build a query for Cat_1 so as to obtain article_1 and article_2?

Comment: If you don't mind some added complexity in exchange for faster and simpler lookup, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061092/django-category-and-subcategory-searches/2066742#2066742

Comment: I would recommend looking into django-mpt or django-treebeard to help model your hierarchical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is:

```
def retrieve( category = None ):
  if( category )
    _cat = category
  else:
    _cat = Category.objects.get(...)

  if( _cat.parent ):
    return retrieve( _cat.parent )

  return _cat
```

I hope this can help.